# Dexie.js query with .equals not working with localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, indexeddb, dexie

I am trying get a value from indexedDB with Dexie.js but it does not recognize the value from localStorage.

I tried async/await, promises, placing localstorage call on created, mounted, outside export default, and none of these ways worked.

```js
fetchData() {
  return dbDexie.tactics1
    .where('i')
    .equals(localStorage.getItem("id")) // Here is the problem
    .toArray()
    .then((r) => r[0].f);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`.equals`](https://dexie.org/docs/WhereClause/WhereClause.equals()) strict equality

The `equals` method is a strict equality test, so if `id` is a number type in `indexedDB`, then the string type returned from `localStorage` won't match, because of the different types. And `localStorage` only stores strings.

For this reason, it's common to see `JSON.parse` used when retrieving data from `localStorage`, to convert serialized data :

```js
fetchData() {
  return dbDexie.tactics1
    .where('i')
    .equals(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("id")))
    .toArray()
    .then((r) => r[0].f);
},
```

Or you could more explicitly cast the `localStorage` value to a Number type:

```js
.equals(Number(localStorage.getItem("id")))
```